# Undefined reference to `COMP_zlib@libcrypto.so.10' (and others)

Tags: openssl, redhat

I am working on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.0 (Maipo). The server provides OpenSSL 1.0.1. I am getting a lot of crypto errors when trying to link to OpenSSL.

Here is my link command command line (order like in the command line):

```
g++ -g -O2 -Wl,-rpath -o output file1.o  libprivate_lib1.so -Lprivate_path -llib1 -ldl \
-lpthread -llib2 -lexpat -lgtest -lgtest_main -lboost_regex -lboost_filesystem -llzma \
-lcrypto private_lib2.so private_lib3.so -llib3
```

Here are some of the errors:

```
/lib64/libssl.so.10: undefined reference to `COMP_zlib@libcrypto.so.10'
/lib64/libssh2.so.1: undefined reference to `EVP_get_cipherbyname@libcrypto.so.10'
/lib64/libssl.so.10: undefined reference to `X509_STORE_free@libcrypto.so.10'
/lib64/libssl.so.10: undefined reference to `BIO_clear_flags@libcrypto.so.10'
/lib64/libssl.so.10: undefined reference to `d2i_KRB5_AUTHENT@libcrypto.so.10'
/lib64/libssl.so.10: undefined reference to `MD5_Transform@libcrypto.so.10'
/lib64/libssl.so.10: undefined reference to `X509_VERIFY_PARAM_set_depth@libcrypto.so.10'
/lib64/libssh2.so.1: undefined reference to `DSA_do_verify@libcrypto.so.10'
/lib64/libssl.so.10: undefined reference to `SHA384_Init@libcrypto.so.10'
/lib64/libssl.so.10: undefined reference to `PEM_ASN1_read_bio@libcrypto.so.10'
/lib64/libssl.so.10: undefined reference to `FIPS_mode@libcrypto.so.10'
/lib64/libssl.so.10: undefined reference to `OBJ_find_sigid_algs@libcrypto.so.10'
/lib64/libssh2.so.1: undefined reference to `BN_bn2bin@libcrypto.so.10'
/lib64/libssl.so.10: undefined reference to `EVP_rc2_40_cbc@libcrypto.so.10'
/lib64/libssl.so.10: undefined reference to `sk_num@libcrypto.so.10'
...
```

when I am running:

```
ll /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so
```

I am getting

```
/usr/lib64/libcrypto.so -> libcrypto.so.1.0.1e
```

and when running:

```
objdump -tT /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.1e | grep COMP_zlib
```

I get

```
000000000013e500 g    DF .text  0000000000000002  libcrypto.so.10 COMP_zlib_cleanup
000000000013e460 g    DF .text  000000000000009e  libcrypto.so.10 COMP_zlib
```

so it means that I have it in this library.
The strangest thing is that it is able to link in redhat 6.5/4 but failing with redhat above 7.
any suggestions ?

Comment: The question is unclear and there may be plenty of potential causes. We don't even know *what* you're trying to link or which versions of which tools you're using, and how you're using them (e.g. CLI args), and so on.

Comment: Perhaps you forgot to link to libcrypto ? Add the `-lcrypto` linking flag **after** the flags for linking to libssl. Or perhaps you're trying to link in some incompatible library that you have compiled on a machine thats not compatible with Red Hat 7.0. At any rate, it's a good idea to describe your problem in detail, e.g. show us the actual command you ran that produced this output.

Comment: I am linking with crypto lib (added the command line). I think it is related to redhat 7. because it is able to compile on redhat 6.5/4.

Answer (score 0):

Functions like `COMP_zlib` and `EVP_get_cipherbyname` are part of the OPenSSL SSL library, and not the Crypto library. You have `-lcrypto` but you appear to be missing `-lssl`:

```
g++ -g -O2 -Wl,-rpath -o output file1.o  libprivate_lib1.so -Lprivate_path -llib1 -ldl \
-lpthread -llib2 -lexpat -lgtest -lgtest_main -lboost_regex -lboost_filesystem -llzma \
-lcrypto private_lib2.so private_lib3.so -llib3
```

You should change to `-lssl -lcrypto`:

```
g++ -g -O2 -Wl,-rpath -o output file1.o  libprivate_lib1.so -Lprivate_path -llib1 -ldl \
-lpthread -llib2 -lexpat -lgtest -lgtest_main -lboost_regex -lboost_filesystem -llzma \
-lssl -lcrypto private_lib2.so private_lib3.so -llib3
```

*If* `private_lib2.so private_lib3.so` depend upon OpenSSL, then `-lssl -lcrypto` needs to be moved after them. That is, use `private_lib2.so private_lib3.so -lssl -lcrypto`.

Also `libssh` must proceed `-lssl -lcrypto`. I don't see where its being linked, but the library may be going by a different name. In the end, you might find it easier to use the library list `<other libs> ... -lssl -lcrypto -llzma -pthread`.

It could also be a newer or different version of OpenSSL is present, but its configured differently. For example, it looks like Red Hat removes compression (`./configure no-comp ...`) but headers are bringing in symbols like `COMP_zlib`.

I guess your next step is to: (1) show a typical compile command, and (2) provide `g++ -v` so we can see the header search paths.

One final thing to keep in mind is you are using `g++`, so linkage with be `extern "C++"` by default. It could be one of those old OpenSSL headers lacks the customary:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

...

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

I don't have access to a Red Hat server, so I don't know for sure. I test another library using both CentOS and Fedora, but I know differences exist on occasion.